# Android edittext get only one input character

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText in my app with textChangeListener that convert number format on afterTextChanged.

this is my EditText in layout file:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/zone_name"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/margin_shape_table"
            android:paddingStart="8sp"
            android:paddingEnd="8sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

and this is my listener code:

```
zoneName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            String char1 = s.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() > 0){
                zoneName.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                zoneName.setText(converter.convertNumbers(s.toString()));
                zoneName.addTextChangedListener(this);
                zoneName.setSelection(s.length());
            }else {
                zoneName.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that when I run it on Asus ZenPad8.0 (android 6.0.1) it only get first entered character and after that "Editable s" contains only first character.
I have this problem on this device only and for other devices it gets full entered text.

Anyone have any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: Just.a suggestion, have you tried seeing what happens if you remove the line of code removing the text changed listener?

Comment: @tomerpacific if I do this, it will stuck in a loop. Because in textChangeListener will set text again.

Comment: Then have you tried running the code on a different device with the same Android OS version and seeing what happens?

Comment: @tomerpacific Yes, and it's ok on other devices with same or even different android version. But in AsusZenPad 8.0 it has problem. Even I test it on different Asus ZenPad devices and all of them have problem.

Comment: Then it is something with OEM. I would advise to maybe contact them or seeing if this issue is something someone else has encountered.

Comment: seems like a bug with Asus default keyboard, problem resolves by using any other keyboard as well, have you find any update on the matter? @Mohsen

Answer (score 0):

the bug is with the `Asus ZenUI's keyboard` and you may add `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` to avoid the issue.
for more complete answer please check my answer to another question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55933884/3880796